# Bindings problem on Internet Information Server

Tags: iis, https, binding

Under a Windows Server 2012 R2, there are 4 subdomain hosts which we have secured with Let's Encrypt certificates and the Certifytheweb software.

All of them work correctly under HTTP and HTTPS, except one that does not work under HTTPS.

- admin.xxx.com <- works http, NO https <- Server returns ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
- admintor.xxx.com <- works both http & https
- tor.xxx.com <- works both http & https
- rsv.xxx.com <- works both http & https

The DNS is correctly pointed, ports are open, etc.

**Command : netsh http show sslcert**

```
IP:puerto                      : [::]:443
    Hash del certificado             : c27c23de235f34dc4ec169f791ce38628da2e2bd
    Id. de la aplicación               :  {ba195980-cd49-458b-9e23-c84ee0adcd75}
    Nombre del almacén de certificados       :MY
    Comprobar revocación de certificado de cliente : Enabled
    Comprobar revocación usando solo el certificado de cliente almacenado en caché  : Disabled
    Comprobación de uso                  :  Enabled
    Hora de actualización de la revocación    :0
    Tiempo de espera de recuperación de dirección URL        : 0
    Identificador de Ctl               : (null)
    Nombre del almacén de Ctl          : (null)
    Uso del asignador de DS              : Disabled
    Negociar certificado de cliente : Disabled

Nombre de host:puerto                : tor.xxx.com:443
    Hash del certificado             : 3809c072eadfd24730a8a84430f977de10649c4e
    Id. de la aplicación               :  {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
    Nombre del almacén de certificados       :My
    Comprobar revocación de certificado de cliente : Enabled
    Comprobar revocación usando solo el certificado de cliente almacenado en caché  : Disabled
    Comprobación de uso                  :  Enabled
    Hora de actualización de la revocación    :0
    Tiempo de espera de recuperación de dirección URL        : 0
    Identificador de Ctl               : (null)
    Nombre del almacén de Ctl          : (null)
    Uso del asignador de DS              : Disabled
    Negociar certificado de cliente : Disabled

Nombre de host:puerto                : rsv.xxx.com:443
    Hash del certificado             : fe9511a9695b697eeb716ee5fee30dc945721ea9
    Id. de la aplicación               :  {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
    Nombre del almacén de certificados       :My
    Comprobar revocación de certificado de cliente : Enabled
    Comprobar revocación usando solo el certificado de cliente almacenado en caché  : Disabled
    Comprobación de uso                  :  Enabled
    Hora de actualización de la revocación    :0
    Tiempo de espera de recuperación de dirección URL        : 0
    Identificador de Ctl               : (null)
    Nombre del almacén de Ctl          : (null)
    Uso del asignador de DS              : Disabled
    Negociar certificado de cliente : Disabled

 Nombre de host:puerto                : admintor.xxx.com:443
    Hash del certificado             : f34a6f31ddbe975806a51862fde8c57defa43d62
    Id. de la aplicación               :  {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
    Nombre del almacén de certificados       :My
    Comprobar revocación de certificado de cliente : Enabled
    Comprobar revocación usando solo el certificado de cliente almacenado en caché  : Disabled
    Comprobación de uso                  :  Enabled
    Hora de actualización de la revocación    :0
    Tiempo de espera de recuperación de dirección URL        : 0
    Identificador de Ctl               : (null)
    Nombre del almacén de Ctl          : (null)
    Uso del asignador de DS              : Disabled
    Negociar certificado de cliente : Disabled

Nombre de host:puerto                : admin.xxx.com:443
    Hash del certificado             : ff284d45d86d0d9444a459fcc717c867f5918fab
    Id. de la aplicación               :  {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}
    Nombre del almacén de certificados       :My
    Comprobar revocación de certificado de cliente : Enabled
    Comprobar revocación usando solo el certificado de cliente almacenado en caché  : Disabled
    Comprobación de uso                  :  Enabled
    Hora de actualización de la revocación    :0
    Tiempo de espera de recuperación de dirección URL        : 0
    Identificador de Ctl               : (null)
    Nombre del almacén de Ctl          : (null)
    Uso del asignador de DS              : Disabled
    Negociar certificado de cliente : Disabled
```

**ApplicationHost.config**

```
    <site name="admin.xxx.com" id="4" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="admin.xxx.com">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\admin" />
    </application>
    <application path="/pdf" applicationPool="admin.xxx.com">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\admin\pdf" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:admin.xxx.com" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:admin.xxx.com" sslFlags="1" />
    </bindings>
</site>
<site name="tor.xxx.com" id="6" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="torneos.xxx.com">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\tor" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:tor.xxx.com" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:tor.xxx.com" sslFlags="1" />
    </bindings>
</site>
<site name="rsv.xxx.com" id="7" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="rsv.xxx.com">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\rsv" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="192.168.1.5:80:rsv.xxx.com" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:rsv.xxx.com" sslFlags="1" />
    </bindings>
</site>
<site name="admintor.xxx.com" id="5">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="admintor.xxx.com">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\admintor" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:admintor.xxx.com" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:admintor.xxx.com" sslFlags="1" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

**SSL report:**

```
    IMPORTANT: This report might contain confidential information. Mask such before sharing with others.
-----
System Time: 25/01/2024 9:24:48
Processor Architecture: AMD64
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
Server Type: IIS

[W3SVC/4]
ServerComment  : admin.XXX.com
ServerAutoStart: True
ServerState    : Started

BINDING: http *:80:admin.XXX.com

BINDING: https *:443:admin.XXX.com
SSLCertHash: ff284d45d86d0d9444a459fcc717c867f5918fab
SSL Flags: Sni
Testing EndPoint: 127.0.0.1
#CertName: admin.XXX.com [Certify] - 20/01/2024 18:23:45 to 19/04/2024 19:23:44
#Version: 3
#You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
#Signature Algorithm: sha256RSA
#Key Exchange Algorithm: RSA Key Size: 2048
This is not an ECC certificate, so *_ECDSA_* cipher suites cannot be used.
#Subject: CN=admin.XXX.com
#Issuer: CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
#Validity: From 20/01/2024 18:23:45 To 19/04/2024 19:23:44
#Serial Number: 037325AE4A9A40032DF33CF198754DE55DB7
DS Mapper Usage: Disabled
Archived: False
#Key Usage: KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature
#Enhanced Key Usage: Autenticación del servidor (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1),Autenticación del cliente (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
#Subject Alternative Name: Nombre DNS=admin.XXX.com
The host name matches the certificate.
Certificate verified.

[W3SVC/6]
ServerComment  : tor.XXX.com
ServerAutoStart: True
ServerState    : Started

BINDING: http *:80:tor.XXX.com

BINDING: https *:443:tor.XXX.com
SSLCertHash: 3809c072eadfd24730a8a84430f977de10649c4e
SSL Flags: Sni
Testing EndPoint: 127.0.0.1
#CertName: tor.XXX.com [Certify] - 20/01/2024 9:02:24 to 19/04/2024 10:02:23
#Version: 3
#You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
#Signature Algorithm: sha256RSA
#Key Exchange Algorithm: RSA Key Size: 2048
This is not an ECC certificate, so *_ECDSA_* cipher suites cannot be used.
#Subject: CN=tor.XXX.com
#Issuer: CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
#Validity: From 20/01/2024 9:02:24 To 19/04/2024 10:02:23
#Serial Number: 04D609FE062C663366171427439845832E00
DS Mapper Usage: Disabled
Archived: False
#Key Usage: KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature
#Enhanced Key Usage: Autenticación del servidor (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1),Autenticación del cliente (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
#Subject Alternative Name: Nombre DNS=tor.XXX.com
The host name matches the certificate.
Certificate verified.

[W3SVC/7]
ServerComment  : rsv.XXX.com
ServerAutoStart: True
ServerState    : Started

BINDING: http 192.168.1.5:80:rsv.XXX.com

BINDING: https *:443:rsv.XXX.com
SSLCertHash: fe9511a9695b697eeb716ee5fee30dc945721ea9
SSL Flags: Sni
Testing EndPoint: 127.0.0.1
#CertName: rsv.XXX.com [Certify] - 20/01/2024 9:03:21 to 19/04/2024 10:03:20
#Version: 3
#You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
#Signature Algorithm: sha256RSA
#Key Exchange Algorithm: RSA Key Size: 2048
This is not an ECC certificate, so *_ECDSA_* cipher suites cannot be used.
#Subject: CN=rsv.XXX.com
#Issuer: CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
#Validity: From 20/01/2024 9:03:21 To 19/04/2024 10:03:20
#Serial Number: 04929F7663D7A705B8FA2E0780BBF6938E42
DS Mapper Usage: Disabled
Archived: False
#Key Usage: KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature
#Enhanced Key Usage: Autenticación del servidor (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1),Autenticación del cliente (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
#Subject Alternative Name: Nombre DNS=rsv.XXX.com
The host name matches the certificate.
Certificate verified.

[W3SVC/5]
ServerComment  : admintor.XXX.com
ServerAutoStart: True
ServerState    : Started

BINDING: http *:80:admintor.XXX.com

BINDING: https *:443:admintor.XXX.com
SSLCertHash: f34a6f31ddbe975806a51862fde8c57defa43d62
SSL Flags: Sni
Testing EndPoint: 127.0.0.1
#CertName: admintor.XXX.com [Certify] - 20/01/2024 19:28:31 to 19/04/2024 20:28:30
#Version: 3
#You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.
#Signature Algorithm: sha256RSA
#Key Exchange Algorithm: RSA Key Size: 2048
This is not an ECC certificate, so *_ECDSA_* cipher suites cannot be used.
#Subject: CN=admintor.XXX.com
#Issuer: CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
#Validity: From 20/01/2024 19:28:31 To 19/04/2024 20:28:30
#Serial Number: 042109EB005294430196EC729625A54C0DA4
DS Mapper Usage: Disabled
Archived: False
#Key Usage: KeyEncipherment, DigitalSignature
#Enhanced Key Usage: Autenticación del servidor (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1),Autenticación del cliente (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
#Subject Alternative Name: Nombre DNS=admintor.XXX.com
The host name matches the certificate.
Certificate verified.
```

I reboot the maching, IIS Server, IIS website...Any ideas?

Comment: could you share iis site binding snapshot? have you test the site in different browser? try disabling antivirus or firewall and browse the site.

Comment: The information you shared is too limited. Please run a detailed report and include in the question, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Update information with applicationHost.config and SSL report.